# Log all Errors in Jaspersoft Studio

Tags: jasper-reports, log4j

I am trying to find out where is the casting exception occurred in my jrxml, which I create with Jaspersoft studio 6.3.3 I have set my logging according to  the structures [here](http://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/configuring-apache-commons-logging-and-log4j-jaspersoft-studio) and added **net.sf.jasperreports.engine.query.JRJdbcQueryExecuter = ALL** to **logging-config.properties**, `com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver =ALL` hopping to see all error details. But there is no information in log about the casting problem.In studio-common.logis only this error: `Error parsing styled text.
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 100; The element type "br" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</br>".` The casting error is as in the[image: picture]

Comment: Seems to be in a category of a chart of some kind `...charts.fill.JRFillCategorySeries`. Any recent changes in a chart? Any new parameters or fields added?

Comment: Yes, I found the problem in chart. But is it possible to see this in log?

Comment: I am not sure if there is any direct indication which field has the wrong data type. I'd analyse from the stack trace out of the `Exception` window.